# Collapsing toolbar and recyclerview does not collapse when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-toolbar

I implemented the collapsing toolbar in one of my activities and upon scrolling the toolbar does not collapse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:scrollbars="none" />


</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I also added the required libraries to gradle. The toolbar stays at the same spot when scrolling down. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The AppBarLayout needs the CoordinatorLayout.

This view depends heavily on being used as a direct child within a CoordinatorLayout. If you use AppBarLayout within a different ViewGroup, most of it's functionality will not work.

Quoted from developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

Also have a look at these tutorials :
http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: I have another layout inside that recyclerview

Comment: @RainMan: You don't need a LinearLayout in this.  CoordinatorLayout will position the Views accordingly based on their behaviors.  Remove the `LinearLayout`, move the `SwipeRefreshLayout` around the `RecyclerView`, then make the top level a `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: @DeeV, thanks for comment, I did the same method as you described, but now when the content of recycleview is on top of the toolbar.

Comment: @RainMan: Could you add the layout_behavior to the recycler view.
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" and this should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> This code may help you.Define CollapsingToolbar in your Activity and write 
>   the method for expand and collapse.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_car_tracker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.example.user.Activity" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/toolbarbackgroundcolor"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/toolbarbackgroundcolor"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/location"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```